# Run-time error '380' when changing combobox value (using userforms and VBA in Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

This is a very simplified example to demonstrate my problem.
Create a userform with a combobox and commandbutton.
Set the style property of the combobox to "fmStyleDropDownList".
Add the code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ComboBox1.Value = "But then it errors sometimes if I change it here"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox1.Value = "I can initialize to any value I choose"
End Sub
```

When I run the userform I can click the command button all day long without getting any errors.
But, when  I click on the drop-down arrow of the combobox and the text in the box gets highlighted, then the next time I click the command button I get "Run-time error '380': Could not set the Value property. Invalid property value"

Using style="fmStyleDropDownCombo" is not an option I want to consider. I tried using `ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1` to clear the selection but that did not work.

Any ideas on how I can reliably avoid this error?

Comment: Are both values already added to the combobox list?

Comment: Hi . I've shown every step of the process from creating a new excel file to the error being produced. There are no values in the combobox list.

Comment: I might be wrong but I believe you need to 'AddItem` the values to the combobox first @moreQthanA

Comment: I believe you are wrong. If you follow the steps in the question it should be clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `fmStyleDropDownList` style, your `ComboBox` value must match one of the item in the list but because you did not add any item, your list is currently `Null`.

To test this, make another ComboBox in your Userform and put this in your Userform:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Debug.Print "=== Click ==="
    Debug.Print "ComboBox1 Type: " & TypeName(ComboBox1.List)
    Debug.Print "ComboBox2 Type: " & TypeName(ComboBox2.List)
            
    ComboBox1.Value = "But then it errors sometimes if I change it here"
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ComboBox2.Value = "But then it errors sometimes if I change it here"
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print "ComboBox2 - Error"
    
    Debug.Print "============="
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "I can initialize to any value I choose"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "But then it errors sometimes if I change it here"
    
    ComboBox1.Value = "I can initialize to any value I choose"
    ComboBox2.Value = "I can initialize to any value I choose"
    
    Debug.Print "ComboBox1 Type: " & TypeName(ComboBox1.List)
    Debug.Print "ComboBox2 Type: " & TypeName(ComboBox2.List)
End Sub
```

When you run the Userform, you should see this in the immediate window:

```
ComboBox1 Type: Variant()
ComboBox2 Type: Null
```

Clicking the button (as many times as you like) before clicking `ComboBox2` and you will notice that the output will still be the same. (and no error too because the `List` is still `Null`)

Now click `ComboBox2` and click the button again, you will see that the type for `ComboBox2.List` has now changed from `Null` to `Variant` and will actually trigger the error.

===============

So, to avoid this, you need to populate the `List` first, below shows the `AddItem` method:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ComboBox1.Value = "But then it errors sometimes if I change it here"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox1.AddItem "I can initialize to any value I choose"
ComboBox1.AddItem "But then it errors sometimes if I change it here"

ComboBox1.Value = "I can initialize to any value I choose"
End Sub
```

As far as I know, the preferred way to set a ComboBox value with such style is to loop through the ComboBox `List` property, check its value and change the `ListIndex` once found:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ComboBox1.List(i) = "But then it errors sometimes if I change it here" Then
            ComboBox1.ListIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```